# Selenium: null element returned when XPath copied from XPath checker

Tags: xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to locate an element using `XPath`. I used `XPath` checker and copied the `XPath`. The Selenium IDE can find the element that way, but the following Java code returns no element.

Can someone please help me in this regard.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('mResources')/x:a")) ;
element.click();
```

Thanks

Comment: Biggest difference between IDE and Java Webdriver is that webdriver does not wait for page to load properly. Do you have some waiting in your code?

Comment: `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('mResources')/a")) ;

element.click();` try this.

Answer (score 0):

Or better as answer. To my java code, I impelemented "better" find approach

```
private Webelement foundElement;
public WebElement find(By by){
    for (int milis=0; milis<3000; milis = milis+200){
        try{
            foundElement = driver.findElement(by);
        }catch (Exception e){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();  
            }
        }
    }
```

And later in my code I have something like:

```
WebElement element= find(By.xpath("id('mResources')/x:a"));
           element.click();
```

The `find()` does the same as `findElement` but in loop, every 200 miliseconds, for maximum 3 seconds.